# FileAppender with maxHistory

Tags: logback, log4j2

I am writing a batch application. It is desirable for me to create a new log file at each new application launch. I am tempted to use [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)'s [Uniquely named file](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#uniquelyNamed). So if I run the batch application 100 times, it will create 100 log files. I also desire a maximum number of 30 archive files to keep and asynchronously deleting older files. Here is [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492022/how-to-roll-the-log-file-on-startup-in-logback) asking the same. But I do not want to write code, is there a way to easily achieve that using logback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [log4j2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)'s [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender). It has a "OnStartup Triggering Policy" which is perfect for batch applications.