# Rollover logfile on startup and on time and size

Tags: java, logging, logback, rollingfileappender, log-rotation

Using logback, and its `RollingFileAppender`, how can I configure a log to roll over on time and size, but also on every application launch?

The following config generates a new log file on each day, and when the previous one gets too big.
However, it will not generate a new log file when the application is restarted.

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

How can I also trigger a rollover when the application is started?

I could include the application start time in the filename pattern, by referencing

```
<timestamp key="startTime" datePattern="HHmmss" timeReference="contextBirth"/>
```

However this would screw up automatic archival and cleanup, and every subsequent log file until restart would contain that startup timestamp as well, even on the following days. Ideally I would prefer if the filenames do not contain any timestamps.

There is an old question from 2010 dealing with the same problem: [How to roll the log file on startup in logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492022/how-to-roll-the-log-file-on-startup-in-logback)

However that question does not use `SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy`, which did not exist at the time, and the answers do not work with the current version of logback, since the interface and the internal classes changed quite a bit since then.

Comment: Have you looked at the source yet?

Comment: As a last resort before posting here, sure, but without any success. The SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy seems impossible to extend to trigger rollover on startup. All relevant methods are hidden in SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP, when I override isTriggeringEvent to return true on first call, i get a NullPointerException, and so on. If you see a way without reimplementing the whole thing, please let me know.

Comment: Last time I had to deal with this we restarted the application daily so the "single file per invocation with a time stamp and no rollover" worked for us.  I then added code to a subclass of the appender that cleaned up old logs at startup which I could bring in as part of the application (logback sees the full application classpath).    I have not looked at the source since.